# use tv as second monitor and show fixed area

Tags: c#, split, screen, multiple-monitors, television

I am trying to code a program in C# for a waiting room in a clinic.
the program works like this :

-add paitient name into db
- give him a number for example "1"
- add the room 
- when it comes it's turn the program display in tv the number "1" and the name of the room and ask patient to go to the room

the problem is how to make the number and the name of the room to be displayed on tv rather than the whole screen of the computer

Comment: What an awesome homework problem and yet a serious lack of effort

Comment: The question makes no sense. How is the TV involved?  Do you mean a physical TV as the monitor or a Software TV application running inside the monitor....

Comment: physical TV as the second  monitor that shows only a full screen form contains  The number and the room name

Comment: Michael Randall lack of effort I did code the app and everything works the problem is to show another seprate form in Maximised mood contains the number and the name of the room in the tv minitor

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try breaking the problem down into steps. I suggest ignoring the TV to start with and trying to get it to work on your PC. Think about the end result, maybe something like "Mr McFly to Doc Brown please", and the steps you need to take to get there. If you've got a specific question please feel free to ask. You'll likely get a better response than a broad "do this for me".

Comment: okay thank you I'll do it for you

Comment: @user3438908 no offense intended. but you have to look at it from an external point of view. There is a serious lack of information here to help you and a lot of ambiguity